# Laravel/Eloquent query too slow (join, orderBy count)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-query-builder

I have a model Person.php with a one to many relationship to Pet.php. I need to sort persons by the count of pets the person has. This query works:

```
$persons = Person::join('pets', 'persons.id', 'pets.person_id')
    ->select('persons.*', DB::raw('count(pets.id) as pets_count'))
    ->groupBy('id')
    ->orderBy('pets_count', 'desc')
    ->limit(100)
    ->get();
```

SQL:

```
select `persons`.*, count(pets.id) as pets_count 
from `persons` 
inner join `pets` on `persons`.`id` = `pets`.`person_id` 
group by `id` 
order by `pets_count` desc 
limit 100
```

The database is seeded with 50,000 persons and 100,000 pets. Sorting by pets_count takes 350ms (while sorting by a persons column without join takes 18ms). I haven't added any indexes.

How can I make this faster?

I could add `pets_count` column to persons, and have to update it often and carefully, and then this query could be sped up without the joins and counts. Is this good practice? Does SO have a `votes_count` column on questions, or do they re-count the votes often?

Comment: I'm guessing the query comes out something like `SELECT persons.*, count(pets.id) AS pets_count

FROM persons

INNER JOIN pets
 ON persons.id = pets.person_id

ORDER BY pets_count DESC` ... so if you chuck an `EXPLAIN` on the start of that and run it directly on the database it might flag something up. As an aside, your people can't share pets? That's mean! ;)

Comment: Oh - I missed the `GROUP BY` : `EXPLAIN SELECT persons.*, count(pets.id) AS pets_count FROM persons INNER JOIN pets ON persons.id = pets.person_id GROUP BY persons.id ORDER BY pets_count DESC` I'm guessing the `ORDER BY` is slowing it down as it's having to re-order the list after selecting everything - and since it's a dynamic *column* - `COUNT(pets.id)` - there can't be an index on it.

Comment: Is your database correctly indexed?

Comment: Quick test: you could try to add index everywhere, it should work better.

Comment: Be careful with the "add index everywhere" approach. For the sake of debugging, it's only needed on columns referenced in the query and even then, the indices will need to be removed afterwards anyway. Indexing everything everywhere will eventually result in _slower_ queries as it'll quickly consume RAM and swap.

Comment: I don't know if it is correctly indexed... it has a primary key ('id')

Comment: I could add a pets_count column to the persons table, and this would speed up. I would also have to update persons.pets_count each time a pet is inserted. Is this a good practice?

Comment: I don't think that would be good to do.  Do you have a foreign key or at least an index on pets.person_id?